# 'System.Net.Http' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Runtime'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm trying to install the [MaxMind MinFraud](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaxMind.MinFraud) package via NuGet. Whenever I try, I get the following back -

```
PM> install-package MaxMind.MinFraud
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Net.Http (≥ 4.0.0)'.
install-package : 'System.Net.Http' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Runtime'.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package MaxMind.MinFraud
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

A few other similar questions here suggested restarting VS, manually adding a reference to System.Net.Http and clearing NuGet Package Cache, and changing the target framework to 4.6.2 (originally 4.5), all of which did not work for me.

Any ideas on what I can try next?

Comment: Is this issue occurs in one specific project or all projects in your Visual Studio? And which version of Visual Studio and NuGet do you use?

Comment: Please try install the System.Net.Http package standalone to check whether this package could be installed correctly. And also try create a new project to install these packages.

Comment: I got it working, thanks to your comments, @Wendy. I tried to install the System.Net.Http package from NuGet, and got told I needed a later version of NuGet installed. I followed the prompts, which installed an update to VS 2012 (which is what I was using). I then tried again, and was told installing the System.Net.Http package required and **even later** version of NuGet. I dug around on the NuGet site, and found that  the version required wasn't even listed for VS 2012. I spent the afternoon installing VS 2015 (which I should have ages ago), tried again, and it all worked.

Comment: @Wendy Feel free to write an answer, and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed this package successful in my Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 project with NuGet Package Manager 3.4.4.

So please make sure your are using the latest version of Visual Studio 2015 and NuGet Package Manager.